# Including assets in subdirectories with config.assets.precompile in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

I've got a Rails 3.1.3 application running on Heroku, utilizing S3 for asset hosting via `asset_sync`.  Included in my `app/assets/css` directory is a subdirectory with two files: `main.css.scss` and `categories.css.scss`.  I have the following line in my `production.rb`:

`config.assets.precompile += [ 'admin/main.css.scss', 'admin/categories.css.scss', 'print.css', 'products.css.scss', 'services.css.scss' ]`

When I push to Heroku, all my assets are precompiled and uploaded with the exception of those two files.  Do I need to perform some sort of dark magic to include those two files in the process?

Comment: You're supposed to use the name of the compiled asset (ie drop the .scss) but I don't know why that only affects the files in the subdirectory

Comment: I figured it was something nit-picky like that.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add answer and close question.

Comment: Frederick's comment was correct.  I'll let him make the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Just type the filenames without scss and it will work fine.

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'admin/main.css', 'admin/categories.css', 'print.css', 'products.css', 'services.css' ]
```