# config.assets.precompile not adding vendor/gem assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

I'm having trouble getting vendorized assets to be compiled as root files.

I want to have the following assets available standalone (not packaged with other assets_:

```
vendor/gems/neo-viz/app/assets/stylesheets/neo-viz.css.scss
vendor/gems/neo-viz/app/assets/javascripts/neo-viz.js.coffee
vendor/gems/neo-viz/app/assets/javascripts/lib/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
vendor/gems/neo-viz/app/assets/javascripts/lib/arbor/arbor.js
```

With the following line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-1.6.1.min.js arbor.js neo-viz.js neo-viz.css )
```

Only the css file is precompiled and made available.  Why?

Also, after seeing this question ( [Including assets in subdirectories with config.assets.precompile in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038867/including-assets-in-subdirectories-with-config-assets-precompile-in-rails) ), I tried:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-1.6.1.min.js arbor.js neo-viz.js neo-viz.css lib/arbor/arbor.js arbor/arbor.js lib/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js   )
```

But it made no difference.  Ideas?

Answer (score 18):

By default Rails only looks into 3 locations: `app/assets`, `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets`. Sprockets looks for JS assets in the sub-directory `javascripts`. E.g.

```
app/assets/javascripts/arbor.js
lib/assets/javascripts/arbor.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/arbor.js
```

If you want to see where Rails is looking for you can use this in the console: `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

What you can do is add your custom path to the pipeline:

```
 # @file: config/application.rb
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "gems", "neo-viz", "app", "assets", "javascripts")
```

Then create a manifest, where you include your JS files:

```
# @file: /vendor/gems/neo-viz/app/assets/javascripts/neo-viz.js
//= require lib/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min
//= require lib/arbor/arbor
//= require neo-viz
```

Finally add your manifest:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( neo-viz.js )'
```

If you still want to add them separatly, which I do not see the point, why not include them in a manifest, then you'll have to add **all** the possible path prefix so Rails knows where to look:

```
 # @file: config/application.rb
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "gems", "neo-viz", "app", "assets", "stylesheets")
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "gems", "neo-viz", "app", "assets", "javascripts")
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "gems", "neo-viz", "app", "assets", "javascripts", "lib", "jQuery")
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "gems", "neo-viz", "app", "assets", "javascripts", "lib", "arbor")
```

Then you can add them like this, since assets outside a manifest must be added to the precompile array:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-1.6.1.min.js arbor.js neo-viz.js neo-viz.css )
```

Source: [2.1 Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

Comment: This was very helpful. It has been such a long time, but this answer should be checked as _accepted_ imo.