# How do I include stylesheets from a gem into the main app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

How do I access the styles in a gem from my main application? I created a 'refinerycms-carts' gem and added this file:

```
refinerycms-carts/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass
```

However, when I reload the page and search for the class in application.css in the browser (F12), it does not find it.

I tried adding this line to main app's app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
@import 'refinerycms-carts';
```

But it gave an error "File to import not found or unreadable: refinerycms-carts."

I also tried naming the file carts.sass but still could not find the class I was referencing.

Yes I'm in development mode. Yes, other changes like controller or models or view are updated and reloaded.

Main app Gemfile: `gem 'refinerycms-carts', :path => '../refinerycms-carts'`

This is in my refinerycms-carts.gemspec: `s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*"] + ["readme.md"]`

This is in my gem Gemfile: `gem 'sass-rails'`

The gem acts as an Engine.

Rails 3.2.14.

Comment: See: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067327/config-assets-precompile-not-adding-vendor-gem-assets

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531563/get-gem-vendor-files-in-asset-pipeline-path

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this in one of my Gem's views:

```
-content_for :stylesheets, stylesheet_link_tag('refinery/carts')
```

I also renamed the file to app/assets/stylesheets/refinery/carts.sass. There was already a `yield :stylesheets` in the app's layout.